# Calling a powershell script from InstallShield project

Tags: powershell, windows-installer, installshield

I'm having a weird problem.

I have an InstallShield project (which creates setup.exe) that contains a custom action item - calling a powershell script.

All the script does is to install 3 adobe reader updates (1 exe file and 2 msp files) on top of the already installed Adobe Reader 11.0.0.

When I'm calling the script my self - it works fine.

However, after the setup.exe finishes, it seems like only one update (the exe file) was really installed (the adobe reader version after the install is 11.00.10 which is the result of running only the exe file..).

All 3 adobe updates sit in the same folder and the powershell script first sets it location to this folder.
When running the updates manually after the installation - it also works fine and updates it to 10.00.22 (what it should be).

Any ideas why is this happening?

Here's my powershell script:

```
    Set-Location  "C:\myProject\adobeUpdates"

Start-Process .\AdbeRdr11010_en_US.exe -ArgumentList '/q /norestart /sPB /rs /msi' -WindowStyle hidden -Wait

ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 10000  # Tried to add a delay but wasn't helpful

Start-Process -FilePath “AdbeRdrUpd11021.msp” -ArgumentList '/qn' -Wait

Start-Process -FilePath “AdbeRdrUpd11022_incr.msp” -ArgumentList '/qn' -Wait
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Can you add a log switch to the argument? Something like '/L*V "C:\temp\patch.log"'  Thinking that this might give you some more information as to why these updates aren't installing.

Comment: powershell lets you just do `Start-Sleep -Seconds 10` by the way.

Comment: Shouldn't you add the "/update" flag when invoking your ".msp" files?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, this is the working script:

```
 Set-Location  "C:\myProject\adobeUpdates"

Start-Process .\AdbeRdr11010_en_US.exe -ArgumentList '/q /norestart /sPB /rs /msi' -WindowStyle hidden -Wait

ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 10000

Start-Process .\AdbeRdrUpd11021.msp -ArgumentList '/qn' -Wait

Start-Process .\AdbeRdrUpd11022_incr.msp -ArgumentList '/qn' -Wait
```

I'm not sure what is the different and would love someone to explain but anyway it works just fine now.